# Trying to resolve a scrapy python for loop

Tags: scrapy

If possible I would like to ask for some assistance in scraping some details from a webpage.
https://www.traxsource.com/genre/13/deep-house/all?cn=tracks&ipp=50&period=today&gf=13

The structure is as follows

[Webpage data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1iVh.jpg)

[Webpage data structure expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRLsF.jpg)

I am able to retrieve all songs using the following command:

```
response.css("div.trk-cell.title a").xpath("@href").extract()
```

or

```
resource.xpath("//div[@class='trk-cell title']/a/@href").get()
```

I am able to retrieve all artists using the following command:

```
response.css("div.trk-cell.artists a").xpath("@href").extract()
```

or

```
resource.xpath("//div[@class='trk-cell artists']/a/@href").get()
```

so now I am trying to perform a loop which extracts all the titles and artists on the page and encapsulate each result together in either csv or json.  I am struggling to work out the for loop, I have been trying the following with no success.

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "traxsourcedeephouse"
        start_urls = ['https://www.traxsource.com/genre/13/deep-house/all?cn=tracks&ipp=50&gf=13']

        def parse(self, response):
                for track in response.css("div.trklist.v-.full.v5"):
                        yield {
                                'link': track.xpath("//div[@class='trk-cell title']/a/@href").get(),
                                'artists': track.xpath("//div[@class='trk-cell artists']/a/@href").get()
                                }
```

As far as I can tell the "trklist" div appears to encapsulate the artist and title div's so I'm unsure as to why this code doesn't work.

I have tried the following command in the scrapy shell and it doesn't return any results which I suspect is the issue, but why not?

**response.css("div.trklist.v-.full.v5")**

A push in the correct direction would be a lot of help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You only select the table which contains the items, but not the items themselves, so you're not really looping through them.
2. The CSS selector to the table is a little different on scrapy so we need to match it (no v5).
3. Inside the loop you're missing a dot inside `track.xpath(...)`.
4. Notice in the code that I added "hdr", I did it in order to skip the table's header.

I added both CSS and xpath for the for loop (they both work, choose one of them):

```py
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "traxsourcedeephouse"
    start_urls = ['https://www.traxsource.com/genre/13/deep-house/all?cn=tracks&ipp=50&gf=13']

    def parse(self, response):
        # for track in response.css('div.trklist.v-.full div.trk-row:not(.hdr)'):
        for track in response.xpath('//div[@class="trklist v- full init-invis"]/div[not(contains(@class, "hdr"))]'):
            yield {
                'link': track.xpath(".//div[@class='trk-cell title']/a/@href").get(),
                'artists': track.xpath(".//div[@class='trk-cell artists']/a/@href").get()
            }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, Thank you very much

Comment: @Jason No problem, I will appreciate if you could accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In scrapy shell if you execute view(response) to view your response in web browser. You will find that there is no data because data is generating dynamically using javascript where scrapy does not work.
You should use selenium or other.

Comment: I did try selenium previously, is there a particular method I need to follow?

Comment: As far as I know, there is not particular method to follow to extract the javascipt related content.